# Get value of variable quantile per group

Tags: pandas, quantile

I have data that is categorized in groups, with a given quantile percentage per group. I want to create a threshold for each group that seperates all values within the group based on the quantile percentage. So if one group has q=0.8, I want the lowest 80% values given 1, and the upper 20% values given 0.

So, given the data like this:

[image: Data]

I want object 1, 2 and 5 to get result 1 and the other 3 result 0. In total my data consists of 7.000.000 rows with 14.000 groups. I tried doing this with groupby.quantile but therefore I need a constant quantile measure, whereas my data has a different one for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
num = 7_000_000
grp_num = 14_000
qua = np.around(np.random.uniform(size=grp_num), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group": np.random.randint(low=0, high=grp_num, size=num),
    "Quantile": 0.0,
    "Value": np.random.randint(low=100, high=300, size=num)
}).sort_values("Group").reset_index(0, drop=True)

def func(grp):
    grp["Quantile"] = qua[grp.Group]
    return grp

df = df.groupby("Group").apply(func)
```

Answer: (This is basically a for loop, so for performance you can try to apply [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to this)

```
def func2(grp):
    return grp.Value < grp.Value.quantile(grp.Quantile.iloc[0])

df["result"] = df.groupby("Group").apply(func2).reset_index(0, drop=True)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
         Group  Quantile  Value  result
0            0      0.33    156       1
1            0      0.33    259       0
2            0      0.33    166       1
3            0      0.33    183       0
4            0      0.33    111       1
...        ...       ...    ...     ...
6999995  13999      0.83    194       1
6999996  13999      0.83    227       1
6999997  13999      0.83    215       1
6999998  13999      0.83    103       1
6999999  13999      0.83    115       1

[7000000 rows x 4 columns]
CPU times: user 14.2 s, sys: 362 ms, total: 14.6 s
Wall time: 14.7 s
```